# Do I wait or do I have to do something about it?

Tags: electrum

Nooby question here, I payed/sent an amount and it failed somehow, so I tried again and again. 
I checked their website and it´s all "failed" or incomplete. But is has a checkmark(sent) on Electrum. This was saturday, today is monday.

Now my question is, do I just wait and the BTC will comeback, or should I do something so it isn´t floating around?

Thanks in advance, 
Alain

PS: Print so you have more details. 
https://gyazo.com/41e1f54c1bb11d1739e6a8da3664911b

Comment: On [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1ExqG8kud3pVSSoSnnU5LVbLZwrSsyqoPf), you can see that it was confirmed. It's done, there should be nothing you have to do now.

Comment: Thanks for your fast input!
It happens on the site, it shows this. Status:Failed, so where did it go wrong? 
See: https://gyazo.com/1698c27aa052679aca2d0842a5427e5a

Comment: I don't understand what the list on the website shows, but since it shows many Faileds, are you sure that it's not a scam website?

Comment: It shows that I had sent money first, and then I had no more bitcoin on electrum, so it probably failed because of that. 
But I continued to try to send money, because it was failing to send (so in my head when it failed means I still have money in the account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **do I just wait and the BTC will comeback**

No, the transaction `be13...5f1b` is complete and 0.00361861 BTC (about EUR 18.86 at time of writing) has been sent to address `1Exq...qoPf`

Nothing is going to come back just by waiting

The transaction, like all confirmed Bitcoin transactions, is final and irreversible.

> **should I do something so it isn´t floating around?**

It isn't floating around. It has been moved to address `1Exq...qoPf`. It can be spent by whoever has the private-keys from which that address was derived.

> **I payed/sent an amount and it failed somehow**

This is an issue with whatever software/website is showing the "failed" message - you should ask the owner of that website (or developer of that software).

Comment: Is it really not possible to track which address belongs to who ? The company says the money never got to them. 

I try to check their address and everytime it comes a different one to send the BTC to, is this changing address a reference or their address, because if it is theirs, it should not change?!!

Comment: @Alain. Bitcoin is designed to make it nearly impossible to find the owner of an address. It is normal to be given a different receiving address for each transaction. This is partly for privacy reasons and, in this case, so that the recipient can work out which customer sent the money. Note: bitcoin "addresses" are not the address of a place, person, wallet or any other thing. They are just a number (technically a kind of hash-number mostly generated from an encryption key) that is used in a mathematical operation that underpins the integrity of the Bitcoin blockchain.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for dumbing it down RedGrittyBrick !!

So strange though, I copy pasted their "hash" sent, then some failed payments notice were shown, although it got confirmed from blockchain, and now the company says it failed and they never got the money, although I don´t have it either on my balance.. sucks

Comment: @Alain addresses changing for every transaction is normal. However they did hand out that address to you in the past and you sent them money. Now you need to confront them with a link to blockchain.com showing that address received money. If they don't credit you with this amount consider them scammers.